# VNC Playing video

Tags: vnc, vlc-media-player, tightvnc, ultravnc, chickenvnc

I'm watching videos with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) & [Media Player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-media-player) through a TV.

I'm controlling the pc using VNC via a laptop.

My problem is that if the video is being played, it comes through on the vnc client (the laptop).  This makes vnc very slow (lag etc) because it is trying to update so often.

Is it possible to prevent the video being played through the client?  Is this a VNC setting or a Windows setting?

I've tried using [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) and [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) on the server and [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) on the client.  The results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just make VNC stop some content - you may have luck changing the encoding method or quality, or even if the client supports it - only bringing one application through, but, VNC just isn't good at this.

If you can, I would recommend trying to use Remote Desktop (If Windows) or if you are trying to just control VLC and don't need full machine access, try taking a look at one of the other alternate controls for VLC such as telnet.